# update with max value of the column is not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried to set the `max` value for the particular column but that is not working for me. I do not know where i'm going wrong.

```
UPDATE `upload_video` 
             SET order_id ='select max(order_id)+1 
             FROM upload_video' 
             WHERE `video_id` = 22
```

This is my query i run the `select max(order_id)+1 from upload_video` query separately which is giving the result. But if i use this query in update query, the query is executing without error. But the `order_id` is not updating properly. please help me

Comment: For a start you can't spell `UPDATE`

Comment: user1672694 i changed that now but still it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is almost correct in standard SQL, you only need to use brackets `()` instead of apostrophe `'`:

```
SET order_id = (SELECT MAX(...) ...)
```

but MySQL doesn't allow you to update a table while selecting from the same table, a workaround is to use a subquery that calculates the value that you need, and to join your subquery with the table you need to update:

```
UPDATE
  upload_video JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(order_id),0)+1 max_id
                     FROM upload_video) s
SET
  upload_video.order_id=s.max_id
WHERE
  video_id=22
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/577b7b/1).

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in the statement, you used `UPADTE` instead of `UPDATE`.

One problem is, don't quote the subquery. You have used single quotes, which means the expression `select max(order_id)+1...` was interpreted as a text literal (a varchar). But you clearly don't want that (I guess order_id is a number). What you want instead is to evaluate the subquery. However, if you try:

```
UPDATE `upload_video` 
         SET order_id =(select max(order_id)+1 
         FROM upload_video) 
         WHERE `video_id` = 22
```

then MySQL doesn't allow it (I didn't know about that). Other databases such as PostgreSQL allow it. So you might need two statements:

```
select @id = coalesce(max(order_id), 0) + 1 FROM upload_video;
UPDATE `upload_video` SET order_id = @id WHERE `video_id` = 22;
```

Please note this works in MySQL but not in other databases.

Comment: The above query is showing the error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'upload_video' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: You are right, I didn't know about this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The answer from fthiella (`update ... join`) is clearly more elegant, but I leave this answer here as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `upload_video` 
SET order_id =(select COALESCE(max(U2.order_id),0)+1 
         FROM upload_video U2)
WHERE `video_id` = 22
```

Peraphs this query goes in error because MySql doesn't want to use the same table in UPDATE and in subquery.

If your case please write two queries.

The first get the maximum value, the second does update

Comment: You're setting `order_id` to a string.

Comment: @Joe Taras This is resulting the same. No changes